# Property 'url' does not exist on type 'string' JSON

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am trying to send the `url` of some JSON I get when I upload something to azure blob storage. The object is `req.files`. When I `console.log` the `req.files`, I get something similar to this:

```json
[
  {
    fieldname: 'chooseFile',
    originalname: 'video.mov',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'video/quicktime',
    container: 'asset-afe1b5d0-cf8f-11eb-9615-13b96d691770',
    blobPath: '1623950892848-aGxhZC5tb3Y%3D.mov',
    url: 'https://cdn.example.com/item/this/that'
  }
]
```

If I try to, say, `console.log` `req.files.url`, I get an error something like this:

```
Property 'url' does not exist on type '{ [fieldname: string]: File[]; } | File[]'.
  Property 'url' does not exist on type 'File[]'
```

So I've tried this:

```js
const filedata = JSON.stringify(req.files)
console.log(filedata)
```

which returns something more like this:

```json
[{"fieldname":"chooseFile","originalname":"video.mov","encoding":"7bit","mimetype":"video/quicktime","container":"path","blobPath":"item.mov","url":"https://cdn.example.net/this/path/here/there"}]
```

Now if I try to `console.log` `filedata.url`, I get an error like this:

```
Property 'url' does not exist on type 'string'
```

Comment: `filedata` is a string.  That's what `stringify` returns. And, `req.files` is an array

Comment: well as you can see, what you are logging is an array, so you should do something like this: `console.log(filedata[0].url)`... but most importantly, instead of `JSON.stringify` you probably want to use `JSON.parse`

Comment: `req.files` appears to be a collection (array) of objects, each of which represent a file. You need to note which file you're trying to access like so: `req.files[0].url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite all the comments and answer that claims that this is an array, after a look through the source code of the package, I see `JSON.parse`. No, this is not an array. I was doing everything right. This was an unrelated Typescript error. I fixed it by changing the type of `req` from `express.Request` to `any`. Then `req.files.url` will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue here is that `req.files` is an array, not an object. So you should be accessing `req.files[0].url` to access the first element in `req.files` then get its `url` property.

The second issue is trying to get the property `url` after `JSON.stringify`ing the array. `JSON.stringify` returns a string representation of a JS object, and a string doesn't have a `url` property.

As such, you most likely mean to `console.log(req.files[0].url)`, assuming you know that `req.files` will only ever have one element in it, or that you only ever need the first element.

Comment: As it turns out, I began to dig through the code of this package that creates `req.files` and sure enough I found `JSON.parse`. It's not an array.